# Trying to understand functions and how they are called with an exercise

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am interested in Python and started reading `Think Python by Allen B. Downey`. I am a complete beginner and do not know anyone in my circle of friends who programs so I decided I will ask my question here, however simple it may be.
I am currently in the section related to Functions and can not make sense of an example/exercise which involves concatenation:

```
def cat_twice(part1, part2):
    cat = part1 + part2
    print_twice(cat)
```

In the book this is described as storing a local variable in a function. In previous chapters of the same book all exercises are done in the Python Shell IDLE. As far as I understood in order to call a function after something is stored in it you do this:

```
cat_twice()
```

Yet when I do this I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#63>", line 1, in <module>
cat_twice()
TypeError: cat_twice() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'part1' and 'part2'.
```

What exactly am I not getting or doing wrong? why isn't the program running?

Comment: When you call `cat_twice()`, what two values is it supposed to concatenate? Python can't read your mind. You have to give it two values.

Comment: Absolutely. That's why I tried: cat_twice(part1, part2)  and got                    
 File "<pyshell#62>", line 1, in <module>
    cat_twice(part1, part2)
NameError: name 'part1' is not defined

Comment: Nothing is "stored in it", but the function itself. `cat_twice('a', 'b')` - it will not then "remember" `a` and `b`.

Comment: A function takes arguments, you pass those along when you "call" the function. hence `cat_twice('a', 'b')`. The function then "remembers" the sum/join of `'a'+'b'` (`part1 + part2`) for a brief second in a variable called `cat`. But after the function is done executing, `cat` is forgotten/discarded (there's more to it tho). It's a temporary placeholder to store the result of `part1 + part2` somewhere so the function can work on the "new" data, for instance doing a `print(cat)` or `print_twice(cat)`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here is, your function is expecting two arguments, i.e., part1 and part2, compulsorily. When you are calling your function, you have to call as follows:

```
cat_twice(1,2) # assuming are trying to add two numbers in your function
```

If you are trying string concatenation, I would recommend you to look up `join()` function in python.

If you want to have a variadic function which can take either of part1 or part2 as an argument, or both or none of them, you can assign certain default value in method signature, for example,

```
def cat_twice(part1=None, part2=None)
    ...
    ...
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cat_twice(part1=<something>)
    cat_twice(part2=<somethingElse>)
    cat_twice(part2=<some>, part1=<someMore>)
    cat_twice(1,2) # here 1 will be passed as part1 and 2 as part2
```

Keep in mind that if you have assigned None as default to function parameters, the have a None check before performing addition operation or you may lead into `TypeError` for adding unsupported operand types.

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here a Simple Example, i have defined a function cat_twice which will print two values that are passed to it.
Then i passed two values by calling it like cat_twice() simple :) .

```
def cat_twice(part1,part2):
    print(part1+part2)    #this is the code in the function that will execute

cat_twice(1,2)     #this is known as calling function
```

Answer (score 0):

The "cat_twice" function contains the function "print_twice".
Be sure that python has run this function first, so that "cat_twice" can reach "print_twice" when it needs to.

It can be included at the start of the block.
Try:

```
def print_twice(bruce):
    print(bruce)
    print(bruce)
    """Defines the print_twice function"""

def cat_twice(part1,part2):
    cat=part1+part2
    """the print_twice function now feeds into line 9"""
    print_twice(cat)
line1='bingtiddle'
line2='tiddlebang'

cat_twice(line1,line2)
```

I am also alone in learning python, I did a few bootcamp course on Udemy.
Think Python is a far better book for actual learning.
This is the first advice I have felt confident enough to give, so I hope it works.
I have reached chapter 4 so far.
Good luck